# Sitecore - Placeholders - multiple items but restrictions for one specific type

Tags: c#, razor, sitecore, sitecore8

is there a possibility in Sitecore to have a placeholder which can contain many items, but only one per specific item?
I want to achieve something like:

1. Placeholder

   1. Item X (only one is allowed)
   2. Item Y
   3. Item Y
   4. Item Z
   5. Item Z
   6. Item Z
   7. Item X **(no allowed, you can't do this!)**
   8. Item Q

I am not Sitecore specialist

Comment: Not sure I follow your example. Wouldn't the second Y and second and third Z be disallowed?

Comment: @DanSolovay No, the thing is I want to disallow only next Xs. Other items (like Y, Z, Q) can be added as many, as you like.

Comment: If I understand you right, you can do this with "Placeholder Settings Rules" as a module. There are a few open source projects describing how this works on github as well as module on Sitecore marketplace though I'm not sure what state that module is in right now.

Comment: Could you sent me links with an examples of that kind of description? I tried but I can't find it...

Thank you for your time DanSolovay and mikaelnet!

Comment: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Placeholder_Settings_Rules.aspx as a module. I don't know if it's updated, but maybe it's reflectable.
I found this repo on GitHub. I haven't tested it myself, but it looks promising: https://github.com/williamsk/SitecorePlaceholderSettingsRules
(I have lib myself, but can't currently share it as it's owned by a customer)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out!